# Windows Gadgets: Why are settings deleted when my gadget is closed?

Tags: javascript, widget, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm currently in the development and testing phase of my gadget. I've noticed that for some reason, whenever my gadget is closed the settings I've saved are deleted. I'm sure because I've monitored 'Settings.ini'. Why is this? Will it happen when my user restarts their computer, and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a late answer, but when you press X on a gadget it removes the settings for it.

If you simply restart sidebar.exe all of the settings are preserved (This is a quick way of imitating a user restarting their computer)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a guess from my side, as i haven't done much gadget development, but it might be because you can create multiple instances of dacht gadget with their own settings (like a London clock and a New York clock).

It Should not lopers settings on restart as you dont close the gadget but instead you just close the whole gadget engine, but this behaviour can easily be tested by a restart or maybe even a logout and login.